# MongoDB health check failed org.springframework.boot.actuate.mongo.MongoHealthIndicator"

Tags: mongodb

> org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:87);at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2592);at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:499);at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeCommand(MongoTemplate.java:403);at org.springframework.boot.actuate.mongo.MongoHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(MongoHealthIndicator.java:46);at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:84);at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68);at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getHealthStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:103);at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaHealthCheckHandler.getStatus(EurekaHealthCheckHandler.java:99);at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshInstanceInfo(DiscoveryClient.java:1382)

Comment: Can you narrow down any process where this is happening? The "Health Check" is actually an internal part of the *Spring Mongo* driver abstraction. It can be *disabled*, but generally you should not since it's doing useful things. This is probably more indicative of problems with your MongoDB Server/Cluster and/or the network connections in between. Generally this should not occur as a result of code alone. Unless your code is doing something extremely *"taxing"* on the server(s) itself. Also, not the best way to post a question purely with a title and a stack trace. Some research is expected.

Comment: This happen once my Netflix pattern micro services startup and not coming up on Eureka server . This micro services has spring boot connection with mongodb.